# Proving a homotopy is continuous

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

If $H$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$, and $H'$ is a homotopy of $g$ to $j$, then

$F\left(x,t\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       H(x,2t) &,\text{ if } 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}\\
       H'(x,2t-1) &, \text{ if } \frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$

is a homotopy from $f$ to $j$.

I can see that this is a transitive property, but I can't seem to find a way to show that this mapping is continuous.

I know to show continuity I must show that $V \in T' \Rightarrow F^{-1}(V) \in T$, but I can't see how to show that $F^{-1}(V) \in T.$

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This follows from the pasting lemma.  If the domain of $F$ is $X\times[0,1]$, the restriction of $F$ to $X\times[0,1/2]$ is clearly continuous, since it is obtained by composing the continuous functions $H$ and $(x,t)\mapsto (x,2t)$.  Similarly, the restriction of $F$ to $X\times[1/2,1]$ is also continuous.  Since these sets are closed, by the pasting lemma $F$ is also continuous on their union, which is all of $X\times[0,1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by composing the continuous functions $H$ and $(x,t) \mapsto (x,2t)$?  What's the composition?  I'm unfamiliar with the $\mapsto$ notation.

Comment: Define $g:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1/2]$ by $g(x,t)=(x,2t)$.  Then $g$ is continuous, and $H=F\circ g$.

Comment: Why wouldn't the map $g$ you defined map from $[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,2]$ since $g(x, 1) = (x,2)$?

Comment: Oops, I meant $g:[0,1]\times[0,1/2]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Why did you choose $[0,1]$ for the first factor of the domain and codomain of the products?  The initial product space in the homotopy is just an arbitrary space $X$, are you just using $[0,1]$ as an example?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed you were talking about a homotopy of paths.  Yeah, the first coordinate should be whatever the domain of your maps are.

Comment: @EricWofsey How to prove that $X \times [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ is closed in $X \times [0, 1]$?